# Server side SSL SHA1 connection check

Tags: ssl, certificate

we're going to exchange our sha1 certificates with sha2 certificates. We asked our clients to exchange their sha1 client certificates. Before we disable the sha1 certificate on the server, we would like to have an idea about how heavily the sha1 certificate is still used.

Do you know a way how to listen to the network device and list connections established over time with a given certificate?

Comment: What server-side application? How is the SSL handled? E.g. Apache's mod_ssl has the possibility to specify its own log format, including the cipher used to establish the connection: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ssl.html#logformats - so one can process the logs and see which ciphers are in use and how much.

Comment: The server side application is an SAP webdispatcher. I wasn't able to find information about its capabilities in this regard, so I hoped to find something that can operate on the interface directly.

Comment: Well, I would try to put the Apache HTTPD as a proxy in front of the SAP Web Dispatcher, and configure the logging there.